# Additionally pushed items are undefined when trying to access via index in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 3 nested for loops which loop through the array of objects in the objects' property and those array items have their own properties.

```
props = currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties
```

I can use `materialProp` to display the data but to assign I have to do it to currentCell object because if I assign it to `materialProp` it doesn't save it. (It uses another library for drawing graph and it has to save values to cells.)

Whenever I try to display `{{ currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key1][index][key] }`} or    `{{ currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key1][index] }}` it does the job and loops fine but as soon as I invoke function which pushes one more item to the array `{{ currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key1][index] }}` doesnt render aditional elements only those that there before but `{{ key1 }}` and `{{ index }}` on their own are rendered fine and are being created in the dom.

```
<div v-for="(prop, key1) in props" v-if="key1 === 'ingredients' || key1 === 'components'">
         <div v-for="(material, index) in prop">
                    <div v-for="(materialProp, key) in material" class="form-group row">

                        {{ currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key1][index][key] }} // this one is displayed only as many times as there were items in the initial array and doesn't respond to push 
                        {{ key1 }} // this is rendered fine as many times as you push 
                        {{ index }} // this is rendered fine as many times as you push 

                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how are you calling the `push` function?

Comment: I have a button   `<div v-if="key1 === 'labour' || key1 === 'ingredients' || key1 === 'components'"
                    ><a href="#" @click="addItem(key1)">+</a></div>` that does  `this.currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key].push({ ... });`

Comment: if the new item is pushed properly by this call `this.currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key].push({ ... });` try after that the following code : `this.currentCell.attributes.attrs.properties[key].slice();`